# Using IntelliJ to diff two arbitrary files

Tags: intellij-idea, diff

I'm really liking the IntelliJ diff tool. I'm wondering if it is possible to use this tool to diff two arbitrary files. I.e. files NOT in an IntelliJ project. Just pick two files in the file system and diff them?  What about if I want to diff two strings? In my text editor, I'd just create two new documents, paste the text in and diff them, then not save the files when done. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5299914#5299914  (search that forum for "diff command line" (or similar) for other similar threads)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Found this command line:

**on MacOSX: (IDEA EAP 11)**

```
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 11.app/Contents/MacOS/idea diff /Users/ben75/file1.txt /Users/ben75/file2.txt
```

On MacOSX it can't run when IDEA (11) is open.

**on Windows: (IDEA EAP 12)**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0\bin\idea.exe" diff C:\Users\ben75\file1.txt C:\Users\ben75\file2.txt
```

It runs even if IDEA is already open.

I have trouble when trying to compare files with no extensions (or extensions that don't match )

**Directly from IDEA (EAP 12)**

Not so easy, but it works...

- File > Open... > select "file1.txt"
- File > Open... > select "file2.txt"
- Create a "Favorite list" and add both files to this favorite list.
  (to do this : ctrl+right-click on file name tab in the editor > add
  to favorite > select the favorite list just created - see screenshot)
- Finally, open the "Favorites" view (Alt+2 or click on it on the left or your IDEA windows).
- Select both files
- Right click : "compare two files" (or ctrl+D)

[image: add to favorites]

Comment: Just CRTL + D on 2 files that are selected. No need struggling with favorites.

Comment: The question is explicitly about two ARBITRARY files, not already in the project view. You can't select two files that do not exist in any view, thus you have to create favorites for them.

Comment: I always struggled with this and started drag'n'drop these files into my project, just to compare them and delete them afterwards. Adding favorites is a nice workaround.

Comment: @TimoTürschmann  `.bashrc` <=== `alias idiff='"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.2\bin\idea64.exe" diff  '`

Comment: I've added this function to my zsh config `idiff() { "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea" diff "$(realpath $1)" "$(realpath $2)" }`, it allows to execute `idiff` on relative paths too

Comment: @rshmelev this is still working for me Idea64 2019.1.2

Comment: A related workflow is to add a new empty Favorites List and drag one or more folders (containing one or more files you would like to diff) into that list. Select any opened file tab in the editor. Right click on any file in the Favorites folders and choose "Compare File with Editor" (Intellij IDEA 2021.2.2) Oddly, on macOS, drag+drop seemed the only option to add folders to Favorites.

Answer (score 67):

IntelliJ Idea 13 has a feature labeled **Compare with Clipboard**. This feature compares the current open file with a version that you have copied into your clipboard. It's a great, easy way to compare and merge two files easily. It can also be used to compare two arbitrary blocks of code. Can't figure out why one block works and another does not? Use this feature.

This option is present under **View > Compare with Clipboard**. I assigned an easy to remember keyboard shortcut to give me quick access to this feature.

[image: View > Compare with Clipboard]

Comment: This is a really handy feature when migrating code from one Intellij project to another.

Comment: That's really cool, I looked for something like that under the Edit menu, and when I couldn't find it, assumed IntelliJ didn't have it! :)

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to open up a blank diff window to allow comparisons of two different pieces of copy/pasted text? I do this all the time, but now working with Mac it seems all the diff tools want to work with files only. It's useful for grabbing bits of text out of documents to see what's changed, diffing just one function in a file, etc.

Answer (score 62):

**Since 2018.2, IntelliJ has officially supported it**:

**For windows:** Ctrl + Shift + A, then type "Open Blank Diff Window"

[image]

[image]

**For Mac:** Cmd + Shift + A then type "Open Blank Diff Window"

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like this approach. That Diff window even supports drag and drop from the file system!

Comment: Or, for those allergic to memorizing key combos, select the Help/Find Action… menu item, and type “Open ” (not “diff,” unfortunately).

Comment: You could also add your own key shortcut in Settings. Once the  Blank Diff Window is open, I drag and drop files from File Explorer or any location

Answer (score 43):

Select 2 files in *Project* panel and **press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>**.

[image]

Comment: how do you select 2 files that aren't in the project ?

Comment: I put in there by drag and drop to the project, to some dedicated folder. Then just select them - by CTRL key on keyboard + right click by mouse on the table. (I use idea 12 just in case). Make sure you select 2 files but not 3 or 1. My point is - no need to use favorites.

Comment: Ok but the question was about files that aren't in the project.

Comment: They are not to be in the project eventually (they are just temporary guests if you will). Otherwise: It might be costly for some guys like me to type paths in command line, pointing two files (especially if paths are long). Maybe you are right. This depends on point of view what is meaning 'not in the project'. I suppose they are guests to be compared, nothing wrong if I drop them there.

Comment: Copy them into some arbitrary dir in project, compare and delete them..

Answer (score 15):

I have found even better way if you need to compare opened file with any arbitrary file on filesystem:

- Be in editor of the first file, let say A.java.
- Ctrl+Shift+A, you will see:
  [image: Actions search list]
- Select second "Compare With..." option, you will get "Select path" dialog:
  [image: Select path dialog]
- Select any file on you hard drive and confirm it, you will get diff window:
  [image: Diff windows with an arbitrary file against originally selected one]

Answer (score 8):

From the terminal, you can use the idea launcher directly like so:

```
# Windows
idea.exe diff path1 path2

# MacOS/Linux
idea diff path1 path2
```

At least for MacOS (I'm not certain of Windows), if you've created the Command-line Launcher via "Tools -> Create Command-line Launcher..." it's as simple as the following:

```
# Create some files to diff
echo "This is line 1" > file1.txt
echo "This is line 2" > file2.txt

# Diff with IntelliJ
idea diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

Note this works with other JetBrains applications as well; for example, using WebStorm or PyCharm:

```
# Diff with WebStorm
webstorm diff file1.txt file2.txt
# Diff with PyCharm
charm diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

[Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-differences-viewer.html)

Answer (score 7):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2, you can open an empty Differences Viewer and paste any text you want to compare in its left and right panels. The new Open Blank Diff Viewer action can be found in the Find Action dialog.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can (of course, if we are talking about `text` files). But probably you will need to create some project (just for opening there files).

Then your steps will be:

1) Add to created project file#1 and file#2.

2) Open file#1 in editor

3) Right click mouse in left menu (project files browser) on file#2 and find menu-item `Compare File with Editor`.

[image]

That's all. After p.3) a comparison windows will be opened.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I could do the diff that way. I was attempting to figure out if I could skip going through a project and just do the diff. I suppose I could ask another question for a recommendation for a text editor that has a diff tool like intelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

In order to compare two files that both aren't in the project, the following works for me in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 14.1.7 on Windows:

1. Open the first file in the IDE (either by dragging from Windows Explorer into the window, or by File / Open).
2. In the view menu, choose "Compare With…"
3. In the "Select Path" dialog that appears, select the second file (either directly, or by dragging from Windows Explorer into the dialog).

It then opens up in the traditional file comparison pane. If you try to edit one of the files, it presents the usual "Are you sure you want to edit a file that's not in your project" dialog, which one can accept if that's what one is trying to do.

Comment: This is actually a lot easier than creating projects are using favorites list!

Answer (score 3):

In 2022, Help -> Find Action... -> "Open Blank Diff Window", or make a keyboard shortcut for it.

In the Open Blank Diff Window you can paste or open any file, whether
it's in the project or not.

Comment: This method does separate the contents from the file names, but it is rather useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just select both files in project structure and hit:

**Windows:**
ctrl+D

**Mac:**
command+D