# How can I diff two arbitrary code inIntelli J

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I want to use compare tool in intellJ to compare codes.
I checked this post, but the solution is to compare two files, which is not convenient enough. 
[Using IntelliJ to diff two arbitrary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386488/using-intellij-to-diff-two-arbitrary-files)

I want to open a compare tool, and both side is blank. Is it possible to do this?

I tried these two options, but they are not worked as I expected...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to open a compare tool, and both side is blank. Is it possible to do this?

Yes. Use Open Blank Diff Window via Find Action.